# p:poll blows up with 'property not found' error

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to work with the p:poll JSF tag, and using a code sample I found on the net. But I keep getting an error. The system doesn't seem to find the property 'increment', although it exists in the bean.

I use the following:

```
<h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{navBean.count}" /> 
<p:poll actionListener="#{navBean.increment}" interval="1000" update="txt_count" />
```

It is inside a view, and form, like this:

```
<f:view>
<h:form>
```

with the appropriate closing tags. When I hit it, it generates a Property 'increment' not found on type com.roberts.ui.NavBean

The increment method is there:

```
public void increment(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
    count++;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got around to doing this. Here's a full description & code:

Download the latest prime faces from here: http://www.primefaces.org/downloads.html

Get the documentation pdf, 3.0.RC2, from here: 
http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html

The xmlns for this latest release is: xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"

In the xhtml file (for doing the poll every 3 seconds):

```
<h:form>
<h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{counterBean.count}" /> 
<p:poll listener="#{counterBean.increment}" interval="3" update="txt_count" />
</h:form>
```

In the CounterBean:

```
private int count = 1;

public int getCount() {  
    return count;  
}  

public void setCount(int count) {  
    this.count = count;  
}  

public void increment() {  
    setCount(getCount() + 1);  
}
```

That's all. It works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use a panelgrid in this way:

```
 <h:form>
    <p:poll actionListener="#{navBean.increment}" interval="1000" update="panel_to_refresh" />
 </h:form>

 <h:panelGrid id="panel_to_refresh">
    <h:outputText id="txt_count" value="#{navBean.count}" /> 
 </h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Vincenzo, but it doesn't work. I'm still getting the same /pages/testing.xhtml: Property 'increment' not found on type com.ui.NavBean exception.

Comment: Also: I'm getting this warning: "This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace." What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Use the parenthesis in the actionListener like this:

```
 <h:form>
  <p:poll actionListener="#{navBean.increment()}" interval="1000" update="panel_to_refresh" />
 </h:form>
```

Comment: Ok but now I get a /pages/home.xhtml: Unable to find method [increment] with [0] parameters.
If I add a no parameters increment method (without the ActionEvent as parameter) then I don't get an exception, but the poll doesn't do anything. In other words it doesn't update the count field.